# How to manipulate Twilio data object? nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, twilio

How can I put the info in variable 'data' into the new variable 'newData'?

```
var accountSid = '12345';
var authToken = "12345";
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken); 

app.get("/results", function(req,res){
   var query = req.query.search
   var newData;

   // Retrieve list of messages
   client.messages.list(query, function(err, data) {
       if(err){console.log(err)} 
       else {
         // Pass info into 'newData'
         newData = data;
       }
   });

console.log(newData);

res.render("results", {data: newData});
});
```

The above code results in 'newData' being undefined.

If do this:

```
        else {
         // Render raw 'data'
         res.render("results", {data: data});
       }
```

The code works fine. However, I want to manipulate the data *outside* of the function.

Comment: Send the data to. function that has a callback or use ```Promises```

Comment: Smells like a race condition, but I'm not really sure how to help without knowing more about the `client.messages.list()` function.

Comment: Why do you need to manipulate the data outside the function? Since Twilio's `list` function returns data in a callback, you will never have the data immediately after calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your use of `newData` into the callback where it's defined:

```
app.get("/results", function (req,res){
  var query = req.query.search
  var newData;

  // Retrieve list of messages
  client.messages.list(query, function (err, data) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
    else {
      newData = data;
      res.render("results", { data: newData });
    }
  });
});
```

The issue is that `newData` isn't being populated until the callback runs, but you're trying to use the value before that happens.

Here's your original code with comments explaining what happens in what order:

```
app.get("/results", function (req,res){
  // 1. This code runs first.
  var query = req.query.search
  var newData;

  // 2. This call is made second.
  client.messages.list(query, function (err, data) {
    // 5. This code runs fifth, after the list call has completed.
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
    else {
      // Pass info into 'newData'
      newData = data;
    }
  });

  // 3. This console.log is third.
  console.log(newData);

  // 4. This runs fourth, at which point the HTTP response has been sent.
  res.render("results", { data: newData });
});
```

Hopefully that makes it clear why your `res.render` call belongs inside the callback. You want it to run after the `list` call has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Deals with it being Async. Basically your render is rendering before it has the contents of callback.